# Bootstrap : Single Button Dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to add Drop down with button in my form, following is my code:

```
<!-- Row 2 -->
<div class="row-fluid col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-2"> <label class="control-label">Data Field Type: </label></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option> Data Field </option>
        <option> Behavior </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

 <!-- Row 3 -->
 <div class="row-fluid col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Data Type: </label></div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
           <li>Action</li>
           <li>Another action</li>
           <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

But: when I click on the Button, it does not show the options ! Please guide ..

Comment: I have copied your code to bootply.com and can see the options http://www.bootply.com/MdCYA8LYa5

Comment: hope this link help you [Link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) / [Link2](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: does all bootstraps JS files are included?

Comment: what you need exactly? Cause works for @SherinMathew

Comment: Sherin, I saw the links where you copied the code and output shows perfect. But the same code isn't showing me the exact output. When i Click on the button it does not show "Action,etc" <li>'s . Still ill check out the inclusions . I think i must have missed an inclusion in the Asp.net MVC view files. Thanks a lot for the prompt help. i will get back if it still doesn't work out.

Comment: all replies helped , Thanks @SherinMathew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you havent included Your bootstrap files.Hope this helps.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/b4pSSSeIhEsfG8agmKbY?p=preview

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.